# Can I use MobaXterm to login via SSH and then enter shell commands?

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I see that I can create an SSH session with MobaXterm and a shell session.

But is it possible to create a session that first logs in and then types shell commands?

I am using the free version of MobaXterm on Windows 10. I am logging in to a remote Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobaXterm supports code snippets that get recorded as a macro and can get replayed on other servers later.

Besides that you have multiexecution of typed commands, that is the commands get executed on different servers at the same time.

check http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html

Comment: Thanks. I now start a session tree times. Then in each terminal I run one macro.